# SQL Insert if record does not already exist inserts anyway

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I am trying to do a and INSERT statement like the one found here: [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

My sql statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1([Name], [Value], [Period], [As of Date])
    VALUES ('Cust Index', -10.75468724987, '1M', '2018-10-31')
    SELECT 'Cust Index', -10.75468724987, '1M', '2018-10-31' 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Name], [Period], [As of Date] FROM Table1
                            WHERE [Name] = 'Cust Index' AND [Period] = '1M' )
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong as this still updates table1 even if the values exist.  I am excluding the [Value] field from my comparison because it is recalculated every time I run my function and I want to make sure it doesn't insert into my table just because it is off by a few decimal places.

Maybe the answer is simple and I just need a second set of eyes to see my sql statement, because as of now I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1([Name], [Value], [Period], [As of Date])
    SELECT v.*
    FROM (VALUES ('Cust Index', -10.75468724987, '1M', '2018-10-31')
         ) v(Name, Value, Period, AsOfDate)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Table1 t1
                      WHERE t1.Name = v.name AND t1.Period = v.Period
                     );
```

This avoids repetition of all the column values.

Note that the best way to ensure non-duplication of data is to use a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_table1_name_period on table1(name, period);
```

Comment: I would use an ID but this eventually will be set up that any user can load data into the database, and I want to make sure if someone tries to upload a report that was already uploaded it doesn't make it in.

Comment: @Mwspencer . . . That is precisely why you want the database to handle the data integrity.  With this construct, two users could insert the same report at the same time.

Comment: Ahh this is amazing for what I need, I can't believe I've never hear of this statement before (create unique index). Thank you sir, I knew I was over complicating it.